# Faster and less cheesy matching of items from 2 collections

Tags: collections, matching

Hi I need to iterate two collections containing different object types and do some matching, adding matched items to a 3rd list.

```
private CheesyMatch( BindingList< MyTypeA > theListA, BindingList< MyTypeB > theListB )
    {
        foreach( MyTypeA item in theListA )
        {
            foreach( MyTypeB item2 in theListB )
            {
                if( item.name == item2.name )
                {
                    item.matched = true;
                    item2.matched = true;
                    MyMatchedList.items.add( new matchedItem( item, item2 ) );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a better/more efficient way to do this?  (I have simplified things a little, as I have some code in my code that copies to new local collections before iterating them, as I was having threading issues.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language this is, but there must be some method liked "exists" or "contains" where you do two loops in series. In pseudo code

```
foreach item in ListA
   if ListB.exists(item) then
      MatchedList.items.add(item)
   end if
endfor
foreach item in ListB
   if ListA.exists(item) then
      MatchedList.items.add(item)
   end if
endfor
```

That way you only go over each collection once rather than doing ListB N times where ListA has N items. Does this make sense?

Comment: really? and what does `exists` do?

Comment: maybe it uses a lower level search on the elements. not sure. you do do a performance analysis if you want in this mystery language.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but I have a 3rd class (MatchedItem) that contains a reference to a TypeA and a TypeB within it (and some other stuff), so I need to add them both at construction time.